# Comprehensive conditional error messages

Tags: javascript, validation, error-handling, conditional-statements

When it comes to dishing out comprehensive errors I'm curious how people generate long if statements without dishing out a message for each possibility.

The benefit of something like the following:

```
if(typeof hello !== "undefined" && hello == 3){

}
```

Is that both conditions are necessary. I've tried experimenting using arrays and objects for if statements like the following.

```
var validate = [
    (typeof hello !== "undefined"),
    (hello == 3)
];
```

Then you can use something like `underscore`'s `_.without()` function to grab `true` vs `false` values and check if there where any errors. The problem with this array above is that if hello is undefined there will be an error.

```
var validate = [
    (typeof hello !== "undefined"),
    (typeof hello !== "undefined" && hello == 3)
];
```

So I have to do this which is very repetitive.

The examples so far haven't given any response back. I just came up with this.

```
var valid = [
    (_.isObject(email)) ? false : "email is not object",
    (dotty.exists(email, "event")) ? false : "event does not exist",
    (email.event == "inbound") ? false : "event is not set to inbound",
    (dotty.exists(email, "ts")) ? false : "ts does not exist"
];
var errors = _.without(valid, false);
if(errors.length == 0) // no errors
```

Which is much more progressive.

```
var valid = [
    (_.isObject(email)) ? false : "email is not object",
    (dotty.exists(email, "event")) ? false : "event does not exist",
    (dotty.exists(email, "event") && email.event == "inbound") ? false : "event is not set to inbound",
    (dotty.exists(email, "ts")) ? false : "ts does not exist"
];
var errors = _.without(valid, false);
if(errors.length == 0) // no errors
```

But I still need to be verbose.

This all brings be to the next idea.

There are two was to process errors.

1. When an error appears, deal with that error before progressing
2. Present all errors

I prefer the latter.

Do any libraries exist to aid in complex if statements for validation purposes?

**UPDATE**

Because the next statement has nothing to do with the previous which is good sometimes, I'm stuck with a crazy slope.

There must be some way to prevent this...

```
typeof email !== "undefined"
typeof email !== "undefined" && _.isObject(email))
typeof email !== "undefined" && _.isObject(email)) && dotty.exists(email, "event"))
typeof email !== "undefined" && _.isObject(email)) && dotty.exists(email, "event")) && email.event == "inbound"
```

v.s the ease of reading

```
typeof email !== "undefined"
_.isObject(email))
dotty.exists(email, "event"))
email.event == "inbound"
```

I want this to be simpler and to not have the slope. In the example below lets say `email` is `undefined` but `color` is and it equals `yellow`. I would love to see the following error report

```
(typeof email !== "undefined") ? false : "no email",
(_.isObject(email)) ? false : "email isn't object",
(dotty.exists(email, "event")) ? false : "event not present",
(email.event == "inbound") ? false : "event not inbound",
(typeof color !== "undefined") ? false : "no color",
(color == "yellow") ? false : "color not yellow",

[
    "no email",
    "email isn't object",
    "event not present",
    "event not inbound",
    false,
    false       
]
```

In other words, I want the color to not return as an error since it's valid. But I want to return all other errors.

Or do I just need:

```
[
    "no email",
    false,
    false
]
```

If `color` and `email` where both undefined I don't just want to see:

```
[
    "no email"
]
```

This is misleading. I would want to see at least

```
[
    "no email",
    "no color"
]
```

Or all

```
[
    "no email",
    "email isn't object",
    "event not present",
    "event not inbound",
    "no color",
    "color not yellow"
]
```

More sloping examples:

```
var valid = [
    (typeof email !== "undefined") ? false : "email is undefined", // halt the code 
    (typeof email !== "undefined" && _.isObject(email)) ? false : "email is not object",
    (typeof email !== "undefined" && dotty.exists(email, "event")) ? false : "event does not exist",
    (typeof email !== "undefined" && dotty.exists(email, "event") && email.event == "inbound") ? false : "event is not set to inbound",
    (typeof email !== "undefined" && dotty.exists(email, "ts")) ? false : "ts does not exist"
];
var errors = _.without(valid, false);
if(errors.length == 0) // no errors
```

Comment: Is what you're trying to do automate calling validation scripts while maintaining a verbosity of each invalid condition?

Comment: @JaredFarrish I suppose so.

Comment: It sounds almost like you're talking about a [rules engine](http://www.jboss.org/drools/) (note, that's Java but the concept applies). So you might look for Javascript rules engines, maybe [JSON Rules](http://code.google.com/p/jsonrules/)? Maybe [Node.js nools](http://c2fo.github.com/nools/) could be useful somehow.

Comment: @JaredFarrish These are pretty interesting resources. Thank you very much. I would like to share with you an idea that came to me, which was to use objects and refer to them within the next if statements. Saves space and offers great error response. https://gist.github.com/reggi/5202723

Comment: This [nools example](https://github.com/doug-martin/nools/blob/master/examples/validator/index.js) looks *really* similar to what you're driving towards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the recommendations in the comments `nools` is a very interesting resource.

- https://github.com/doug-martin/nools
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm